# Load data row in to textboxes after Cellcontent click

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a problem, I've been searching a few hours now with no luck.

What i want to achieve is the following. After you click on a cell in a `datagridview`, I want another tab to show and load the row *(data like customer number pay amount)* in to a few `textboxes`. Doe anyone have some examples or some good suggestions for this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your information suggest a next approach:

Create a event handler for datagridview event `CellDoubleClick`(think to use a DoubleClick - you can use what you want)

```
this.datagridview1.CellDoubleClick += dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick;
```

then create a added function

```
void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //here we write code for copying rowdata in your textboxes
    DataGridViewRow dgvr = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
    //if datagridview have a predefined columns then using those objects as:
    this.textboxCustomer.text = dgvr.Cells[this.datagridview1_ColCustomer.Name].Value.ToString();
    this.textboxPay.text = dgvr.Cells[this.datagridview1_ColPay.Name].Value.ToString();
}
```